# Customize search output

Tags: theming

I was trying to modify the search results page using a preprocess function:

```
function arras_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {

    $type = $variables['result']['node']->type; 
    $variables['search_results'] = '';
    $nodeTypes = node_type_get_types();
    $resultTypes = array();

      $resultTypes[$type][] = $variables['result'];


    foreach ($resultTypes as $resultType => $resultTypeResults)
    {
        echo $resultType;
        $value = "";
        // loop through entries
        foreach ($resultTypeResults as $result)
        {
            $value .= theme('search_result', $result,$resultType);
        }

        // add fieldset
        $variables['search_results'] .= theme('fieldset',
            array(
                '#title' => $nodeTypes[$resultType]->name,
                '#collapsible' => TRUE,
                '#collapsed' => FALSE,
                '#value' => $value,
            )
        );

    };


}
```

but I get this error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in L:\wamp\www\drupal\includes\theme.inc on line 830
```

i.e on the line

```
        $value .= theme('search_result', $result, 'cameras');
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Drupal 7 API theme_search_result](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_search_result/7):

> This function is never used; see the corresponding template file
>   instead.

Try overriding the page using [search-result.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search-result.tpl.php/7)

Comment: Which function are you referring to here ?

Comment: theme_search_result. If you call theme('x'), a function theme_x is called in the background. The Drupal API states that theme_search_result is never used and you should use the corresponding template file: search-result.tpl.php

Comment: when we write theme('x') it will look for both theme_x() or x.tpl.php file too as per my understanding.

Comment: Yes, and in this case the API says that you should always use search-result.tpl.php instead of theme_search_result().